# Does the C11 memory model really conflict with common optimizations?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The OP of [a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68484935/2402272) added a comment to it linking a paper entitled [*Common Compiler Optimisations are Invalid in the C11 Memory Model and what we can do about it*](https://fzn.fr/readings/c11comp.pdf), which apparently was presented at POPL 2015.  Among other things, it purports to show several unexpected and counterintuitive conclusions derived from the specifications for what it calls the "C11 memory model", which I take to consist largely of the provisions of [section 5.1.2.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4) of the C11 language specification.

The paper is somewhat lengthy, but for the purposes of this question I focus on the discussion of scheme "SEQ" on the second page.  This concerns a multithreaded program in which ...

- `a` is non-atomic (for example, an `int`),
- `x` and `y` are atomic (for example, `_Atomic int`), and
- `a`, `x`, and `y` all initially have value `0`,

... and the following occurs (transliterated from pseudocode):

---

**Thread 1**

```
a = 1;
```

**Thread 2**

```
if (atomic_load_explicit(&x, memory_order_relaxed))
    if (a)
        atomic_store_explicit(&y, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

**Thread 3**

```
if (atomic_load_explicit(&y, memory_order_relaxed))
    atomic_store_explicit(&x, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

---

The paper makes this argument:

> First, notice that there is no execution (*consistent execution* in
> the terminology of Section 2) in which the load of `a` occurs. We show this
> by contradiction. Suppose that there is an execution in which a load
> of `a` occurs. In such an execution the load of `a` can only return `0` (the
> initial value of `a`) because the store `a=1` does not happen before it
> (because it is in a different thread that has not been synchronised
> with) and non-atomic loads must return the latest write that happens
> before them. Therefore, in this execution the store to `y` does not happen,
> which in turn means that the load of `y` cannot return `1` and the store
> to `x` also does not happen. Then, `x` cannot read `1`, and thus the load of `a` does
> not occur. As a consequence this program is *not racy*: since the load
> of `a` does not occur in any execution, there are no executions with
> conflicting accesses on the same non-atomic variable. We conclude that
> the only possible final state is `a=1 ∧ x=y=0`.

(Question 1) **But isn't that argument fatally flawed?**

The assertion that the load of `a` can only return 0 is made subject to the assumption that `a` is in fact read, which the argument intends to contradict.  But in that case, as the paper observes, there is no *happens before* relationship between the store to `a` in thread 1 and the load from `a` in thread 2.  These are conflicting accesses, neither is atomic, and one is a write.  Therefore, per paragraph 5.1.2.4/25, the program contains a data race resulting in undefined behavior.  Because the behavior is undefined, nothing can be concluded about the value loaded from `a` by thread 2, and in particular, it cannot be concluded from the specification that the load must return `0`.  The rest of the argument then collapses.

Although the paper claims that the argument shows that the program does not contain a data race ("is not racy"), in fact that is not a consequence of the argument but rather a hidden assumption.  Only if, contrary to 5.1.2.4/25, the program did not contain a data race would the argument stand up.

Now perhaps the key is that the argument above considers only "consistent executions", a term defined in a later section of the paper.  I confess that it gets a little deep for me at that point, but if in fact constraining the behavior to consistent executions is sufficient to support the assertion that the load of `a` must return 0, then it seems that it is no longer (just) the rules of the C11 memory model that we are talking about.

This matters because the authors conclude that a source-to-source translation combining threads 1 & 2 to yield ...

---

**Thread 2'**

```
a = 1;
if (atomic_load_explicit(&x, memory_order_relaxed))
    if (a)
        atomic_store_explicit(&y, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

---

... is not permitted of implementations by the C11 memory model, on the basis that it allows executions in which the final state is `a = x = y = 1`.  That this and various other code transformations and optimizations are invalid is the thesis of the paper.

(Question 2) **But isn't it indeed valid for a C11 implementation to treat the original three-threaded program as if it were the two-threaded program consisting of threads 2' and 3?**

If that allows "consistent executions" with results that could not be produced by any consistent execution of the original program, then I think that just shows that C11 does not constrain programs to exhibiting consistent executions.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: In a grand scheme of things, memory models and optimization are seldom a good fit for each other. Vulnerabilities like Spectre and Meltdown can bear witness. :-)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but you might be interested in [CppMem](http://svr-pes20-cppmem.cl.cam.ac.uk/cppmem/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @Hasturkun, that does look interesting.

Comment: I don't follow, @oakad.  I know about Spectre and Meltdown, of course, but I am missing their relationship with the topics on which this question focuses.

Comment: "Grand scheme of things". Prefetch optimization in hardware/microcode. :-)

Comment: This kind of plugs into why we have relaxed memory models in the first place, instead of sticking to sequential only.

Comment: Ok, @oakad, but there is no going without *some* memory model, and the optimizations relevant to the question are those performed by a C compiler, not CPU hardware or microcode.

Comment: The Standard's approach of saying that all actions that might make the effects of optimization observable must be categorized as UB makes it impossible to define the behavior of all programs that should behave predictably without blocking useful optimizations.

Comment: Interesting, @supercat, I don't remember hearing the Standard characterized that way before.  I'll have to think on that for a bit.  In the meantime, do you have any observations about the specific claims discussed in the question?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The logic used here would effectively allow implementations to process almost any program in almost any fashion.  On the other hand, because of the One Program Rule, implementations already have that freedom anyway: if for some implementation there exists some program that exercises the translation limits in N1570 5.2.4.1, and which the implementation processes as mandated by the Standard, nothing the implementation could possibly do with any other Conforming C Program would render the implementation non-conforming.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I consider the questions here as being somewhat analogous to the question of whether an equality comparison between two valid pointers can ever yield behavior which would not be consistent with an expression that arbitrarily yields 0 or 1 with no side effects.  I don't think the authors of the Standard intended that to be the case, but the way N1570 6.7.3.1 paragraph 3 is written can be interpreted as allowing comparisons to have wacky side effects, a freedom both clang and gcc exploit.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Or as a somewhat more goofy example, consider `int x,y; void *p1=&x; uintptr_t up = (uintptr_t) p1; void *p2 = (void*)up;`, if an implementation were to process integer-to-pointer conversion in a manner such that `p2` would hold `&y`, then the program would have violated the "shall" requirement that would forbid pointer-integer-pointer round trips in cases where the result wouldn't compare equal to the original pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, no one is both interested enough and confident enough to write an answer, so I guess I'll go ahead.

> **isn't that argument fatally flawed?**

To the extent that the proof quoted from the paper is intended to demonstrate that a conforming C implementation is not permitted to perform the source-to-source transformation described in the question, or an equivalent, **yes**, the proof is flawed.  The refutation presented in the question is sound.

There was some discussion in comments about how the refutation could be viewed as boiling down to anything being permissible in the event of undefined behavior.  That is a valid perspective, and in no way does it undercut the argument.  However, I think it's unnecessarily minimalistic.

Again, the key problem with the paper's proof is here:

> > the load of `a` can only return 0 (the initial value of `a`) because the
> > store `a=1` does not happen before it (because it is in a different
> > thread that has not been synchronised with) and non-atomic loads must
> > return the latest write that happens before them.

The proof's error is that the language specification's requirement that a read of `a` must return the result of a write to `a` that "happened before" it is conditioned on the program being free of data races.  This is an essential foundation for the whole model, not some kind of escape hatch.  The program manifestly is not free of data races if in fact the read of `a` is performed, so the requirement is moot in that case.  The read of `a` by thread 2 absolutely can observe the write by thread 1, and there is good reason to suppose that it might sometimes do so in practice.

To look at it another way, the proof chooses to focus on the write not happening before the read, but ignores the fact that the read also does not happen before the write.

Taking the relaxed atomic accesses into account does not change anything.  It is plausible that in a real execution of the paper's three-threaded program, the implementation (for example) speculatively executes the relaxed load of `x` in thread 2 on the assumption that it will return 1, then reads from `a` the value written by thread 1, and as a result, executes the store to `y`.  Because the atomic accesses are performed with relaxed semantics, the execution of thread 3 can read the value of `y` as 1 (or speculate that it will do so) and consequently perform the write to `x`.  All speculations involved can then be confirmed correct, with the final result that a = x = y = 1.  It is intentional that this seemingly paradoxical result is allowed by the "relaxed" memory order.

> **isn't it indeed valid for a C11 implementation to treat the original
> three-threaded program as if it were the two-threaded program
> consisting of threads 2' and 3?**

At minimum, the paper's argument does not show otherwise, even if we -- with no basis in the specification -- construe the scope of the UB arising from the data race to be limited to whether the value read from `a` is its initial one or the one written by thread 1.

Implementations are given broad license to behave as they choose, so long as they produce observable behavior that is consistent with the behavior required of the abstract machine.  The creation and execution of multiple threads of execution is not itself part of the observable behavior of a program, as that is defined by the specification. Therefore, yes, a program that performed the proposed transformation and then behaved accordingly, or one that otherwise behaved as if there were a *happens before* edge between the write to `a` and the read from `a`, would not be acting inconsistently with the specification.

#### Addendum

Following the recent alternative answer and in view of the commentary on that, it seems appropriate to include some remarks in this answer about how that one and this one come to different conclusions.

***Main controversy***

The other answer summarizes this key characteristic of the paper's analysis:

> So the check for a "race" (and therefore "undefined behaviour") is done only on the "consistent executions", not on "candidate executions".

The other answer seems to subscribe to that approach, apparently accepting that filtering out candidate executions without regard for the impact of UB is valid.  It does not provide a general justification for that, but in the case of the example program, it claims that it is justified by the spec's rule for which side effects are visible by which evaluations (5.1.2.4/19).

***Objection 1: specifications of UB cannot be disregarded***

The rule cited by the other answer does not express any precedence over the one that indicates that the program's behavior is undefined, nor does it contradict the definition holding that the spec places no requirements on a program with UB.

In practice, the well-established convention for interpreting the spec with respect to UB is that UB indeed has the consequences its definition says it has. No provisions of the spec that otherwise would require particular program behavior apply to programs with UB.
The existence of rules specifying program behavior does not provide any justification for disregarding rules that explicitly specify program behavior to be undefined.  It is in fact the reverse.

***Side consideration: proving UB***

The matter arose in discussion of how one can then prove that a program has UB.  If one is reasoning about a program based on the spec, and arrives at a provision such as 5.1.2.4/24 that specifies the program to have UB, then does that not undermine the chain of reasoning by which that conclusion was reached?

Yes and no.  We could observe that undertaking such a chain of reasoning in the first place necessarily starts with an assumption that the program has defined behavior.  If that allows one to conclude that the program has UB according to some explicit specification, then that contradicts the initial assumption, proving UB *by contradiction*, if not directly.

Alternatively, it is also possible to rely on paragraph 4/2, which says, among other things,

> Undefined behavior is indicated [by] the omission of any explicit definition of behavior

Therefore, even if one rejects the validity of the proof by contradiction, one is left with UB in such cases simply on the basis that the spec does not provide any coherent definition of the program's behavior.

***Objection 2: "consistent executions" are not the only ones allowed by the C language spec***

Consider this simpler program:

- non-atomic, shared `int`s  `a` and `b` are initially 0.
- thread 1 performs `a = 1;`
- thread 2 performs `b = a;`

Following the paper's approach, we exclude from the list of consistent executions any in which thread 2's read of `a` observes a value other than 0, and any in which the final value of `a` is not 1.  That leaves just one consistent execution, but when that execution is analyzed for data races, we find one involving `a`.  What now?

The language spec places no requirements on the behavior of a program containing a data race, so we must reconsider our previous exclusions: *all* candidate executions are allowed (that is, they are consistent with the language spec), even those that are not consistent per the paper.

But what then is the significance of the paper's kind of consistent executions?  And if executions that are not consistent are nevertheless allowed in some cases, then on what basis do we exclude all such executions from an analysis of whether the program contains data races?  In fact, we do want to exclude many candidate executions from that analysis, but I submit that we cannot justify excluding those for which doing so requires assuming absence of a data race in the first place.

***Objection 3: the paper's interpretation is inconsistent with real-world expectations and behavior***

The paper and the other answer suppose that because the non-atomic store to `a` in thread 1 of the example program has no happens-before relationship with the load from `a` in thread 2, the implementation is required to *prevent* the load from observing the store.  That's manifestly untrue, as the previous objection shows, but it's not even a reasonable expectation.

Actual practice and general expectation is that non-atomic accesses follow the natural storage behavior of the machine, not requiring any special attention above and beyond that, including in multi-threaded programs. In a program without data races, the required memory behavior, including for non-atomic accesses, is expected to be assured by correct implementation of atomic operations and other synchronization operations, without any extra requirements on the handling of non-atomic accesses.  That is the underlying basis for 5.1.2.4/19, for example.

The point of attributing undefined behavior to data races is exactly to relieve implementations from satisfying those provisions in a program with data races.  (No doubt specifically with regard to accesses to the racy object, but the committee prefers to use existing tools such as UB, and sometimes paints with a broad brush.)    This is the perspective from which I'm speaking when I say that being race free is foundational, or that the other provisions are contingent on that.  Yes, they are contingent in a technical sense, because *everything* is contingent on the program having defined behavior, but that's the means by which the committee met its objectives to free programs from obligation in the presence of data races.

It is therefore wrong to apply 5.1.2.4/19 or other rules of the memory model without *first* considering whether there are data races.  The paper inverts that relationship.

***Objection 4: the paper thereby creates its own problem***

At least some of the deficiencies the paper's authors claim to have found in the C memory model depend on their model's approach to data races.  A common theme is that executions containing data races are claimed to afford fewer consistent executions than similar ones without, and that that renders various source-to-source translations invalid that the authors claim (and I agree) were meant to be valid.

But those are manufactured problems, resolvable by correcting the model so that it integrates handling of data races in a way that leads to predictions matching the allowable behaviors that we all seem to agree were intended.  Agreement with our expectations is among the primary criteria by which we should judge a formal model such as the paper's.  A model corrected along these lines would be messier to formalize, and I anticipate that it would be weaker, but that just mirrors reality: the C memory model *is* weaker than the paper's formalization of it.

***Closing example of a SEQ execution***

There was some discussion in conjunction with the other question of an example execution of program SEQ that is allowed (or should be), and yields final state a=1 ∧ x=y=1.  Here is one:

| Thread 1 | Thread 2 | Thread 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 store 1 in `a` (non-atomic) | 2.1 load 1 from `x` (relaxed) 2.2 load 1 from `a` (non-atomic) 2.3 store 1 in y (relaxed) | 3.1 load 1 from `y` (relaxed) 3.2 store 1 in `x` (relaxed) |

The full list of happens-before relationships here are

- 2.1 hb 2.2 hb 2.3 (following from the sequenced-before relationships in thread 2)
- 3.2 hb 2.1 (the latter sees the side effect of the former)
- 2.4 hb 3.1 (the latter sees the side effect of the former)
- 3.1 hb 3.2 (following from the sequenced-before relationships in thread 2)

I note that there is a happens-before cycle, but that the memory model does not forbid it.  Each atomic read maps to a corresponding atomic write that happens before it and writes the value that is read. There is a conflicting read and write on `a` with no happens-before relationship relating them, so (and this is where we diverge from the paper) the program behavior is undefined, therefore 2.2 is allowed (as is any and everything else).

Answer (score 0):

**No**, to me the proof doesn't seem flawed.

Section 2 of the paper has the following paragraph:

> We refer to a pair of an opsem and a witness (O,W) as a *candidate
> execution*. A candidate execution is said to be *consistent* if it
> satisfies the axioms of the memory model, which will be presented
> shortly. The model finally checks if none of the consistent executions
> contains an *undefined behaviour*, arising from a *race* (two
> conflicting accesses not related by hb) or a *memory error* (accessing
> an unallocated location), where two accesses are conflicting if
> they are to the same address, at least one is a write, and at least one
> is non-atomic. Programs that exhibit an undefined behaviour in one
> of their consistent executions are undefined; programs that do not
> exhibit any undefined behaviour are called *well-defined*, and their
> semantics is given by the set of their consistent executions.

So the check for a "race" (and therefore "undefined behaviour") is done only on the "consistent executions", not on "candidate executions".

For simplicity, suppose we have "Thread 1" that does just `a=1` and "Thread 2" that does just `b=a`.

Claim: There is a "consistent execution" that results in a=1, b=0, but there is no "consistent execution" that results in a=1, b=1.

Why is b=1 not possible? Because an execution is only "consistent" if the relevant non-atomic write (in this case `a=1`) "happens before" the read (`b=a`). Here "happens before" means "it was **mandatory** to happen before, **not** just by chance due to lack of synchronization". It is evident that it is not mandatory that `a=1` happens before `b=a`, therefore the "candidate execution" which turns out this way is not "consistent".

Then why is b=0 possible? Because, in the relevant "candidate execution", `a` gets its value from its initial value 0, which is already stored there even before both threads begin. So in this execution no "write" to `a` has occurred that violates the "happens before" relation. This makes the execution "consistent".

Here's the catch: a=1, b=0 is the only possible "consistent execution", but that doesn't mean it is actually what the program does. In this case, it contains a "race", which is "undefined behavior", which makes the whole program undefined (may well explode). This is what gives permission to the compiler to also allow the b=1 result, even though the relevant execution is "not consistent".

Now let's look at the actual program in your question.

By the exact same logic as above, the proof asserts that if there is a "consistent execution" that reads `a`, then its value must be 0. You should be able to agree with this now. Then the paper goes on to prove that in such a case "if (a)" should not have occurred. Therefore this "consistent execution" does not exist at all, and since there is no "consistent execution" which reads `a`, this program has no "race" and no "undefined behavior".

This is the logic of the paper, if you follow its definitions.
It seems that you don't want to follow the paper's definitions, but that's fine too! If you prefer, you can look only at the official standard, and you should get the same result, because the paper's definitions are meant to follow the standard.

Can you prove (either from the paper's definitions or from the standard's definitions, whichever your prefer), that the program in your question has undefined behavour? I think not. Because the atomic accesses to `x` and `y` in Thread 2 and Thread 3 in fact conspire to prevent "if (a)" from being reached.

No undefined behavior, and no possibility for a final state with a=x=y=1.

Disclaimer: I haven't read the standard that carefully to confirm the paper's definitions follow it 100% (because the standard is so painful to read that carefully), but it looks very plausible that they do. The paper is well-written, and the use of Coq gives additional credibility because it implies there has been enormous attention to detail so that corner cases have not been overlooked. That's why I am more likely to trust the language of the paper than that of the standard. If you ask me, the standard should have been written in Coq from the beginning.

**UPDATE (Q&A):**

**Q:** It is not logically consistent to trust the language of the paper more than that of the standard. If the two disagree then the standard wins?

**A:** That is, if you are able to read the standard with complete precision and without error. Are you? I should have said I trust the precisely-stated interpretation of the paper more than I trust my own (possibly imprecise) interpretation of the standard, because there are corner cases that I haven't put the effort to consider, but the authors of the paper have, their peer reviewers too, and the authors of the papers that they cite too (collectively, it is a very trustworthy body of researchers). The complete definitions of all the concepts are listed clearly with code, which is as precise as you can get. So my lack of trust is directed mainly towards myself and my own standard-reading abilities. I am not claiming that the standard is vague, I am just saying the closest I can say to that without actually criticizing :).

**Q:** Why do we have to first consider which executions are "consistent", forget the "non-consistent" ones, and only then check for "race" conditions?

**A:** Because apparently that is what the standard says! See 5.1.2.4/19:

> A *visible side effect* A on an object M with respect to a value computation B of M satisfies the conditions:
>
> - A happens before B, and
> - there is no other side effect X to M such that A happens before X and X happens before B.
>
> The value of a non-atomic scalar object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by the visible side effect A.

That last sentence says what the value of a non-atomic scalar object M (the object `a` in our example) shall be. **NOTE:** This is a requirement for the compiler, not for the programmer! It says that, whatever the compiler does, it is required to make sure that if the value of `a` is read, the side effect A (the "write") "happens before" the computation B (the read). And "happens before" is defined earlier in the standard exactly as we (and the paper) have described: not caused by chance due to lack of synchronization, but actually mandated by the program code to necessarily "happen before".

So at the point of reading `a`, in no circumstances can we consider the possibility of any other value for `a` other than 0, unless there is undefined behaviour in the program.

This wording is essentially a filtering-like step: you have a set of "candidate executions", and then the wording in this paragraph of the standard says that just a subset of those executions shall be permitted. The paper calls this set of executions "consistent executions" (it also incorporates other requirements of the standard into this filtering-like step, but this is the one relevant to our example).

After we already have determined what the value of `a` "shall be", we find out that in our simplified example there is a "race condition" (defined by the standard and by the paper in an identical way). On the other hand, in the original example with the atomics, no such race condition is to be found.

So yeah, the standard does (apparently) constrain the programs to exhibit only what the paper describes as "consistent executions", if they are to exhibit something at all without getting into undefined behaviour.

**Q:** Why is the standard written in such a weird way?

**A:** Perhaps because it is not easy at all to do better.

The paper discusses this question:

> **Naive Fix**. A first, rather naive solution is to permit causality cycles, but drop the offending ConsRFna axiom. As we will show in Sections 6 and 7, this solution allows all the optimisations that were intended to be sound on C11. It is, however, of dubious usefulness as it gives extremely weak guarantees to programmers.

The "ConsRFna axiom" essentially corresponds to the paragraph of the standard that we have cited above. The paper claims that if this axiom were to be dropped, the standard would not be useful to programmers. I did not read the paper's Sections 6 and 7 in detail, but it sounds plausible, and anyway I wouldn't expect the standard committee to write it this way if there was an easy better solution.

**Q:** It is plausible that in a real execution of the paper's three-threaded program, the implementation (for example) speculatively executes the relaxed load of x in thread 2 on the assumption that it will return 1, then reads from a the value written by thread 1, and as a result, executes the store to y?

**A:** The compiler is required to make sure that this does not happen. In real hardware it won't. In fact even in the example where there were only `x` and `y` without `a`, that kind of "casualty cycle" won't happen on real hardware. It is just that this fact cannot be deduced from the requirements of the standard (see 7.17.3/15 of the standard), and thus the compiler cannot prove that (for the 3-thread example) its source-to-source and source-to-optimized-itermediate-language transformations are correct. It should be able to prove that source-to-optimized-assembly is correct, but the problem is that the opitimization (and thus the need of proof) happens in a phase before translation to assembly.

**Q:** More detailed explanation about the difference between the x/y-only example and x/y/a example?

**A:** The x/y-only example: there is an execution where `if (x)` returns true and `if (y)` returns true simultaneously because, *in that same hypothetical execution*, the stores of x and y both occur, serving as the sources of the value 1.

In the x/y/a example: there is no execution in which `if (x) if (a)` and `if (y)` are simultaneously true. No way, `if (a)` is `if (0)` and `if (0)` can never be true. This means there is no execution in which the atomic store to y is executed. So `if (y)` cannot be true because there is no source for the value 1 (as the standard says for 42 in 7.13.3/15). And since in no execution `if (y)` returns true, x cannot become 1 either. The only possible execution will will have both `if (x)` and `if (y)` be false. In that execution, `if (a)` is not evaluated, therefore it cannot exhibit a race condition.

The key difference is that `a` never gets its value from a store in some other thread (per 5.1.2.4/19). While `x` and `y` can. And in the x/y-only case they can get the value of 1; if they do, you get a consistent execution that cannot be ruled out, so you have to say it is a valid possible outcome. In the x/y/a case, you can't get `x` and `y` to 1, because the `if (a)` will remove the source for the value 1, and every load must come from an actually executed store (even if executed intuitively in the future).

How this distinction between the x/y-only case and the x/y/a case is implemented in hardware is irrelevant, because in any case in real hardware the x/y-only case does not produce the offending outcome. Theoretically, the compiler just has to make sure that the rules are followed, and it trivially does.

Normally it is OK for the standard to allow superfluous never-occurring-in-practice outcomes because running the program just has to produce one valid outcome. But with program transformation, every outcome of the destination program must come from an outcome of the source program because otherwise you'd be getting a wrong result. So in this context it is no longer OK to allow superfluous outcomes in the memory model. You can't prove that the extra outcomes of the destination are superfluous stuff (and thus not an optimization error), unless you have a definition of "superfluous", i.e. a modified memory model.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256403/discussion-on-answer-by-username-does-the-c11-memory-model-really-conflict-with); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.