# cast char * to void **

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, type-punning

Suppose I have:

```c
char * bufPtr = ...; // points into a char array with at least sizeof(void *) chars remaining
void *ptr1 = ...;
void *ptr2;
```

Assuming that `bufPtr` is properly aligned, are the lines

```c
*(void **)bufPtr = ptr1; // (1)
ptr2 = *(void **)bufPtr; // (2)
```

legal?  I know that `char *` can alias anything, but does that allowance go the other direction?

**UPDATE:** The codebase I'm working on is in C, so that's the language I'm most interested in (if I can only get the answer for one).  I thought C and C++ would be similar in this regard, but maybe I was wrong about that.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255336/discussion-on-question-by-joshua-green-cast-char-to-void); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The answer depends on what `bufPtr` actually points at. There are possible corner cases here, where a `char*` is allowed to point at a `void*` (not converted to/from but actually point at the void pointers physical memory location), or where you use dynamic allocation. The statement "I know that char * can alias anything" is wrong.

Comment: @Lundin, if I do `int x; void *ptr = &x; char *buf = (char *)&ptr;` then I can use `buf` to read the bytes of `ptr`.  That's what I meant by "`char *` can alias anything."  But sure, my case here is going the other direction in that I'm kind of using a `void **` to alias a `char *`.

Comment: Aliasing is a two-directional relation. You cannot go from a character (array) type to a different type by means of a cast and de-reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that char * can alias anything, but does that allowance go the other direction?

**TLDR:**

No.  You can not treat `[un[signed]] char` data as any other type without violating strict aliasing.

However, *untyped* memory is different.  You *can* treat untyped memory a new type via assignment.

**Full Answer:**

Given `char *bufptr`, casting to a `void **` with

```
(void **)bufPtr
```

potentially violates [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Note that the pointer does not have to be dereferenced to invoke undefined behavior - merely *creating* a misaligned pointer is enough to invoke undefined behavior.

Assigning value to the dereferenced pointer with

```
*(void **)bufPtr = ptr1;
```

may or may not violate strict aliasing, depending on what `bufptr` actually points to.

From comments moved to chat, the memory has been characterized as "untyped".  In that case, such an assignment does not violate strict aliasing.

However, the *history* of the use of that memory may impact whether or not the memory remains untyped.  See [**Does C strict aliasing make untyped static memory pools impossible?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484935/does-c-strict-aliasing-make-untyped-static-memory-pools-impossible).  Note in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68485979/4756299):

> Such an allocator is unimplementable in *strictly conforming* C, which is C code that does not rely on an unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior (and does not exceed any minimum implementation limit). It is entirely possible to write such an allocator in *conforming* C, which is C with extensions.

I'd compile the allocator code with `-fno-strict-aliasing` and `-fno-ipa-strict-aliasing` if using GCC, or an equivalent if not.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict-aliasing.

Comment: As my question states, I _know_ that my `char *` is properly aligned to hold a `void *`.  Are the assignments legal under that assumption, or are they simply undefined regardless?  This is where I get confused, as very regularly answers are stated that it's undefined _specifically because of alignment concerns_.

That written, your link looks interesting and I'll have to peruse it later.  For this to work _at all_ we need _some_ allowances, and we can get by without the precise ones in my question; I was just curious if that would be necessary.

Comment: Note that `-fno-strict-aliasing` subsumes `-fno-ipa-strict-aliasing` (so the latter will not prevent any optimizations the former does not already prevent).  In practice, as long as all the reads and writes are the same type, things will be fine without these regardless of the actual type of the object -- that is, all memory is effectively untyped until you write to it, not just malloc'd memory.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen The problem alluded to in the linked question and answer is that your memory pool will become typed as it's used by whatever application is using it.  And your code that manages the memory is "just normal code" and not part of the C implementation.  Therefore your code is subject to C's strict aliasing restrictions.  So you have to rely on extensions such as GCC's `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd But the memory will become typed as it's used.  Also, I recommended both options out of thoroughness.  It's not exactly clear from GCC's documentation how the options interact with whole program optimization, for example.

Comment: This is all fair, and I'll see about using `fno-strict-aliasing` for this part of the codebase (though I feel the precise code here can be safely replaced by calls to `memcpy`).  The point of my question was to ask if ensuring alignment requirements are satisfied is sufficient to make this legal, and the consensus here seems to be "No."  Fine, that's why I asked, but it was frustrating seeing _so many_ comments bring up alignment as a possible concern.